# An error occurred: APINestedStack - Embedded stack XYZ was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [...]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy my serverless application. But, I am getting the following error.

```
Serverless: Typescript compiled.
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: Summary: 80 resources migrated in to 4 nested stacks
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    Resources per stack:
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - (root): 115
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - APINestedStack: 25
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - PermissionsNestedStack: 27
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - PoliciesNestedStack: 1
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - VersionsNestedStack: 27
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
........
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service newteledoc.zip file to S3 (53.61 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
..............................................................................................................................................
Serverless: Operation failed!
Serverless: View the full error output: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3AXXXXXXXXXXXX%3Astack%2Fnewteledoc-dev%2Fa5d283d0-21bb-11eb-ad7c-0a3238f55eb3     
 
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: APINestedStack - Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:stack/newteledoc-dev-APINestedStack-YFRRT1LBBOVU/db403030-21bb-11eb-a0a7-1253d15d20e2 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [ApiGatewayResourceEmployeeEmpidVar]. .

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.17.0
     Framework Version:         1.74.1
     Plugin Version:            3.6.15
     SDK Version:               2.3.1
     Components Version:        2.31.12
```

I am not sure whether this is because of more number of resources or any other issue. Please help me solve this issue.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Goto the cloudformation link in the above log
`Serverless: View the full error output: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3AXXXXXXXXXXXX%3Astack%2Fnewteledoc-dev%2Fa5d283d0-21bb-11eb-ad7c-0a3238f55eb3` and search for `APINestedStack` and check for the failed event you can see the exact reason or error message on why the stack failed.